My Chrome tab memory usage increases with every tab reload going up to 2GB per tab
(My device is an intel based Mac Pro 2019)
On chrome every time a tab is reloaded, the memory usage of that tab increases. A tab with a website starting with 100MB of memory usage goes over 500MB after just a few hours.
This gets worse with the memory saver feature of chrome which automatically stops tabs not being used and then loads them again when they are opened. I have disabled the memory saver in chrome settings otherwise tabs go up to 2GB and chrome starts getting laggy.
I have to reload pages because of web development and because of this I have to close and reopen the tab to avoid the memory bug. Is anyone else with an intel mac facing this issue?

I had tried disabling all chrome extensions but it had not worked before. I just disabled the extensions again and restarted chrome and issue is fixed.
The issue was being caused by an extension that I had installed using chrome's "Load Unpacked" method in the extension settings(it is my own extension). The issue does not happen when I install the same extension from the chrome webstore.
